# Is it possible to have VS2010 and VS2012 projects concurrently on the same source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a VS2010 library project that I would like to use in a new app in VS2012. Of course when I open VS2012 it wants to update the library project. Is there any way of having two projects - one for VS2010 and one for VS2012?

We have a large product portfolio and not all apps will move to VS2012 at the same time.

Comment: Create a new project, and import the files? Save the two project files in different subdirectories.

Comment: If you have VS2010 SP1 you can continue to open a project that has been upgraded to the VS2012 version in VS2010. If upgrading is not an option, there's no reason (other than cleanliness and maintainability) why you couldn't have two projects that both point to the same source code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as long as you're running VS2010 SP1, everything will work appropriately opening the project with both versions of VS.

For C++ compatibility specifically:

> You can use Visual Studio 2012 to open a C++ project that was created in Visual Studio 2010 SP1. If you want to use the Visual Studio 2012 build environment to build a project that was created in Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you must have both versions of Visual Studio installed on the same computer.

The full list of compatibility information can be found on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747(VS.110).aspx)